# How to user can create its own gift hamper and can add product to that hamper

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart, cart

I am developing a new concept magento store with a new functionality of creating gift hamper..i am using **bundle product** in this..

Now i want to create a option on frontend say "**Create hamper**".in this option user can create a hamper/basket with any name using textbox..after creating this hamper user can add products in cart under its gift hamper..

and also on cart page i want to show seprate hamper with its product.

Can somebody help me out in this new concept.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Hello Finally i find out the sollution, its not the exact sollution but very helpful for my new concept,

i can get some help by using & modifying these extension..

have a look on below extension & its respective demo.

http://51328012.demo.aitoc.com/magento-red-furniture-set.html

http://www.magebuzz.com/shopping-list.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/shopping-list.html
http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_gift_registry.html
http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_recurring_purchase_assistant.html#demo
```